# Automatically set post_parent value

Tags: posts, hooks, actions

I'm trying to set my blog posts as children of an /articles/ page. The URL structure is correct, but the breadcrumbs are not.

If I manually set the `post_parent` column in the database to the /articles/ page ID (88) the breadcrumbs are correct.

Is there a way for me to automatically set the `post_parent` column value to 88 for new posts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using `save_post` hook like so:

```
function set_post_parent_on_save($post_id) {
    // If this is just a revision, don't do anything
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Check if it is a post
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_parent_on_save' );

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_parent' => 88 // <- or whatever the parent should be
        ) );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_parent_on_save' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_parent_on_save' );
```

But... It isn't best idea to do this this way and I would rather take a look at the way the breadcrumbs are generated and tried to fix it, so it works properly.

Comment: Thanks. Basically what I'm having to do is not set a post page in the settings > reading because I'm using a module to display the blog posts. If I set the posts page in the settings it automatically creates the breadcrumbs correctly, but then I can't use the module.

Would it be better to maybe NOT set the parent if the parent is already set to 88 from a previous save, or does that not really change anything about it not being the "best idea"?

Comment: It won’t change anything. This code works when you’re saving the post - so it won’t be called very often for given post.